# Xpath/XSLT to return partial string

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm using XSLT 2.0 and xpath 2.0.  I'm having trouble writing an `<xsl:value-of select="">` that would take the leading paragraph number off a paragraph, while still retaining all the elements inside the paragraph. Example from this:

```
<p>(1) This paragraph may have <i>italics</i>, <b>bold</b> and other elements.</p>
```

To this:

```
<p>
  <b>(1)<b> This paragraph may have <i>italics</i>, <b>bold</b> and other elements.
</p>
```

Here is a piece of my verbose code, that partially meets my need:

```
    <xsl:template match="p[substring(.,1,1) = '('][string-length(substring-before(.,')')) &lt; 5]">
    <xsl:variable name="paragraphnumber">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(.,')'),'(')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="parenthesednumber" select="concat('(',$paragraphnumber,')')"/>
    <p>
        <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="$parenthesednumber"/>
        </b>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,$parenthesednumber,'')"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

The template match assures that we're only matching paragraphs that start with `(` and the closing `)` is only 5 characters after that, allowing a 3 character paragraph number or text.

Problem I'm having is the last `value-of` I can get the text, but not the other elements in the para.

Comment: I wonder if this would be better as two templates...one to discover the para and insert a child::b of the p. Then template 2 to take the now un-needed (a) off the beginning of the paragraph text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael Kay suggested, you can do something like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p/text()[1]">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\(.{{1,3}}\)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It searches for the first text node beginning with "(" and ending with ")" with 1-3 characters inside. When applied to an XML input like:

```
<root>
    <p>(abc4) This paragraph may have <i>italics</i>, <b>bold</b> and other elements.</p>
    <p>(123) This paragraph may have <i>italics</i>, <b>bold</b> and other elements.</p>
    <p>(1ab) This paragraph may have <i>italics</i>, <b>bold</b> and other elements.</p>
    <p>(a1) This paragraph may have <i>italics</i>, <b>bold</b> and other elements.</p>
</root>
```

it produces:

```
<root>
    <p>(abc4) This paragraph may have <i>italics</i>, <b>bold</b> and other elements.</p>
    <p><b>(123)</b> This paragraph may have <i>italics</i>, <b>bold</b> and other elements.</p>
    <p><b>(1ab)</b> This paragraph may have <i>italics</i>, <b>bold</b> and other elements.</p>
    <p><b>(a1)</b> This paragraph may have <i>italics</i>, <b>bold</b> and other elements.</p>
</root>
```

Comment: My first use of <xsl:non-matching-substring> .. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Using separate templates is a better approach here, I'd say. By doing so, you ensure "divison of powers" and make it easier to pinpoint wrong code.

The stylesheet below makes use of the regex functionality in XSLT via `matches()`:

```
<xsl:template match="p[matches(./text()[1],'^\([0-9]+\)')]">
```

The template above matches `p` elements if their first text node starts with "(", followed by one or more numbers and ")". If this is the case, the number in parentheses is retrieved - by exploiting the fact that `substring-before()` always targets the first occurence of a search string (here: a whitespace).

**Stylesheet**

EDIT: Suggested by @Erwin Bolwidt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="p[matches(./text()[1],'^\([0-9]+\)')]">
  <xsl:copy>
     <b>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,' ')"/>
     </b>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p|i|b|text()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[matches(.,'^\([0-9]+\)') and parent::p and position() = 1]">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,' ')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><p><b>(1)</b>This paragraph may have <i>italics</i>, <b>bold</b> and other elements.</p>
```

Just for illustration, if your input looks like this:

```
<p>(2) Text1 <b/>(1) Text2</p>
```

The first digit in parentheses should be in a `b` element, the second should remain untouched. This is the output you get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><p><b>(2)</b>Text1 <b/>(1) Text2</p>
```

**Why your approach does not work**

I assume that with this line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(.,$parenthesednumber,'')"/>
```

you intend to output the remaining contents of `<p>`. Yet, you only output the text content of the `p` element, but not its *child elements*. You need to state explicitly that they should be processed, too - for instance by using `apply-templates`.

Comment: Wouldn't that remove `\([0-9]+\)` from the beginning of any text node, not just first text nodes after a `<p>`? I.e. if your input is `<p>Text1 <foo/>(1) Text2</p>` it would remove (1) too?

Comment: You are right. Thanks for spotting this. I'll update my stylesheet.

Comment: The OP wanted to allow a 3 character paragraph number or text. This `<xsl:template match="p[matches(./text()[1],'^\([0-9]+\)')]">` will not select `<p>` nodes starting with `(abc)`.

Comment: I selected Joel's answer, because I like the use of use of analyze string. But I like this answer also.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="p/text()[1]">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\(\d+\)">
   <xsl:matching-substring>
     <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
```

to transform the "p" element into one that includes the extra "b" element in the first text node.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's better to match specifically on the first text node in a paragraph that has a (n) number, it gives you the freedom to use an identity transform to copy over/transform the other nodes (text/elements) in the paragraph.

Caveat: I only have an XPath/XSLT 1.0 processor at hand, but I believe that there is nothing in here that is different between 1.0 and 2.0.

Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="p/text()[1][substring(.,1,1) = '('][string-length(substring-before(.,')')) &lt; 5]">
        <xsl:variable name="paragraphnumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(.,')'),'(')" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="parenthesednumber" select="concat('(',$paragraphnumber,')')" />
        <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="$parenthesednumber" />
        </b>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,$parenthesednumber,'')" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<p><b>(1)</b> This paragraph may have <i>italics</i>, <b>bold</b> and other elements.</p>
```